# CSS gradiente com imagem

Tags: html, css

Preciso desenvolver uma página web responsiva, colocarei uma imagem de fundo como "textura", mas elas não pode ocupar a tela inteira, só até a metade, dando uma transição de fade, entre a imagem e a parte de branco em cima.

Tentei usar linear gradiente, mas ele não aceita imagem. Procurei matérias e ninguem menciona o assunto. Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

[image: A imagem pegaria até a metade +/-]

```
<div class="page-content imagem-fundo">
                    <div class="row container cabecalho-home">...</div>
</div>

.imagem-fundo { background-image: url('../img/poly.png');}
```

Comment: Tem que postar o código que já desenvolveu para passar alguma referências para as respostas.

Comment: Não tem muito o que postar. Na imagem estou usando um background-image. Quero algo como - background-image: linear-gradient(url("IMAGE_URL") 50%, #d13531 50%); Mas isso não fiunciona

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit com forma mais moderna** ([suporte mais limitado dos browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks))

Exitem uma forma mais moderna para fazer essa mesclagem da imagem com a cor do fundo e a técnica é usando **CSS Masks**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a propriedade `-webkit-mask-image` vc vai colocar uma mascara na imagem. A ideia, é que o gradiente que está por cima da imagem na verdade está fazendo um mascara de opacidade sobre a imagem, então onde for pixel preto fica transparente. Veja o código abaixo para entender melhor como foi feito o efeito acima.

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0 0%, #f0f 100%);
}
.imgx {
 width: 100%;
 height: 180px;
 -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 25%, black 100%);
 background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/180);
}
```

```html
<div class="imgx"></div>
```

---

**Versão "antiga" com suporte mais abrangente**

Funciona sim veja o exemplo, repare que no `background-image` eu usei um `linear-gradiente` e uma imagem com o *pattern*

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #fff 50%), url(https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/000/103/376/small/crosshatch-style-background-pattern.jpg);
}
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que estava procurando! Obrigado @hugocsl

Comment: @GabrielMarinho legal que deu certo jovem! Boa sorte com o projeto